# iOS Swift SpriteKit - how to detect time elapsed between user touches on sprites

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, nstimeinterval

I have set up a match-3 game, and I want to track the number of seconds a user takes to touch valid points (game piece sprites) on the game board:
(1) when a game level is loaded, if the user does not touch a sprite within 5 seconds, track this;
(2) while playing the game, if the time elapsed between the user touching a sprite is greater than 5 seconds, track this.
(I will use these results to provide a hint to the user).
I would like to use a NSTimer/NSTimeInterval for this, but not sure how to implement it.

Comment: You don't need to use NSTimer's for this, just set an integer variable and add to it by 1 in the update() function. Then just do simple conversions to get that time in seconds, etc. since update() will add 1 to your timer variable for every frame.

Comment: @BrennanAdler This can be quite unreliable as the frame rate can vary.

Comment: @ZeMoon Unless you are doing hardcore 3D graphics or a ton of stuff it will stay pretty solid at 60 fps. For the game this guy is making seems pretty un memory intensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest adding an integer as others suggested.

All you need is delta time.  I'm assuming you have that part worked out, but I'll post it just in case

**scene properties**

```
// time values
var delta:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(0)
var last_update_time:NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(0)
```

**your scene's update method** (also create an update method for your sprites, and pass `delta` into it here)

```
 func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        if self.last_update_time == 0.0 {
            self.delta = 0
        } else {
            self.delta = currentTime - self.last_update_time
        }

        self.yourSprite.update(self.delta)
```

**your sprite's time properties**

```
var timeSinceTouched = NSTimeInterval(0)
let timeLimit = NSTimeInterval(5.0)
```

**your sprites update / touched method**

```
func touched(){
    self.timeSinceTouched = 0.0
}

func update(delta: CFTimeInterval) {

    if self.timeSinceTouched < self.timeLimit {
        self.timeSinceTouched += delta
    } else {
        // five seconds has elapsed
    }
```